# Update a list with synonyms from a custom csv file if a word in the list is there in the file

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have a list of values which contains product attributes as below:

```
ent_val
['brown', 'shoe', 'Dexter', '7']
```

But the word shoe is not there in the database from which I need to filter out records. I have a synonyms file which contains the word ,synonym as shown below:

```
word    synonym
shoe    footwear
pants   trousers
```

I have a replacers.py  function which will replace a word with it's synonym from the csv.
Now I want to check if any value in my list falls in the column word of the dataframe and if so,my function will be applied to that particular word and replaced with the synonym from the dataframe.
In this case if 'shoe' is a word in the df['word'] then the list will be updated with footwear instead of shoe by using the replacers.py function.

Can someone please help me with this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [136]: ent_ser = pd.Series(ent_val)

In [137]: syn
Out[137]:
    word   synonym
0   shoe  footwear
1  pants  trousers

In [138]: ent_ser
Out[138]:
0     brown
1      shoe
2    Dexter
3         7
dtype: object

In [139]: ent_ser.replace(dict(syn.values.tolist()))
Out[139]:
0       brown
1    footwear
2      Dexter
3           7
dtype: object
```